# Deleting a row in a table mysql hiberhate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, javafx

Deleting a row in a table delete(id) - id highlights red (… cannot be applied to (javafx.scene.control.TableColumn)
I want to delete a row from the database table.

```
               //delete button
            button_del.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, mouseEvent -> {

                int selectedIndex = tableView_tableAll.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
                if (selectedIndex >= 0) {
                    // tableView_tableAll.getItems().remove(selectedIndex);
                    delete(id);
                } else {
                    // Nothing selected
                    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
                    alert.setTitle("Ошибка");
                    alert.setHeaderText("No row selected for deletion");
                    alert.setContentText("Select row in table");
                    alert.showAndWait();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void delete(Integer id ) {
        Session session = utils.HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        ProductEntity productEntity =(ProductEntity) session.get(ProductEntity.class,id);
        session.delete(productEntity);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
```

Comment: Where are you getting the `id` variable you are passing to the `delete()` method? Don’t you need to get this from the item that’s selected?

Comment: @James_D,Yes, I need to get the id of the selected line and remove it from the database. It turns out I id anywhere I do not receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ProductEntity selectedItem = tableView_tableAll.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
delete(selectedItem.getId());
```

or remove deletion by the identifier and immediately delete through the entity

```
private void delete(ProductEntity entity)
...
ProductEntity selectedItem = tableView_tableAll.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
delete(selectedItem);
```